# I am not able to launch an android application from another android application. What to do?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-studio-3.0

I am using `on receive()` to receive broadcast and launch another application(by intent). Whenever the app(wifimann) receives the broadcast, the other app (called kotkot(written in Kotlin)) doesn't launch from initial app despite the Wi-Fi being connected. 
My code is as follows:

- MainActivity:

  ```
  package com.wifi.wifimann;

  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
  import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
  import android.net.NetworkInfo;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }

  }
  ```
- ConnectivityReciever.java:

  ```
  package com.wifi.wifimann;
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
  import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;

  import com.wifi.wifimann.MainActivity;

  public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkCapabilities networkAgent = connMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(connMgr.getActiveNetwork());
  //        NetworkInfo wifi = networkAgent.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
          if (networkAgent.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)){
              Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.kotkot");
              if (launchIntent != null) {
                  context.startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
              }
          }

      }
  }
  ```

  - AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.wifi.wifimann">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
          android:supportsRtl="true"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
          <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
              </intent-filter>
          </receiver>
          <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
      </application>

  </manifest>
  ```

## **It also says that MyBroadcastReceiver is unresolved. But my build.gradle has the same pkg name("com.wifi.wifimann") as its application ID.**

- kotkot:

  - MainActivity:

  ```
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  import android.os.Bundle
  import android.widget.TextView
  import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
  import android.content.Intent
  import android.net.ConnectivityManager
  import android.net.NetworkInfo
  import android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
  import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
  import android.content.Context
  import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
  import android.os.Build
  import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService


  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
          val welcome_greeting: TextView = findViewById(R.id.welcome_greeting)
          welcome_greeting.setText("kotleenhere!!")
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Comment: Write a log before calling startActivity()

Comment: Check the logcat. Your device may be blocking the startActivity because it won't allow to start another app on a broadcast

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman yep I did(in ConnectivityReciever.java). But should it be there?